# Designer changes to winform gridview are not reflected when I run the application

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have a winform application that includes a gridview control.  I can edit the details of the control, which includes a collection of columns.  I can make changes to this, and I can see these changes reflected in the form designer in visual studio and I can also see these changes represented in the generated code in the .designer file for the form.  But when I run the application the gridview columns are unchanged.

For example, the first column has a header of "Asset ID" and if can change that to "Asset ID CHANGED" in the designer and it looks correct.  If I search the entire project for the phrase "Asset ID" the only place it shows up is in the designer file where its showing correctly as "Asset ID CHANGED".

I've tried cleaning before rebuilding.  I've tried deleting my entire /debug folder and rebuilding.  I have no idea where the column definitions are coming from that they remain unchanged.

Comment: I doubt we have enough information to help, but are you sure the columns aren't being modified in your code?

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name!

Comment: Maybe you bind the DGV to a source that is allowed to create the columns?

Comment: Do you have AutoGenerateColumns set to true?